# Android ArrayList.size returns notfound

Tags: android, vector, size

My app add an integer value to a vector, and then wants to know the size of that vector.

```
if(nearSelected||middleSelected||farSelected){
    ArrayList<Integer> distance = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //Which distance(s) has the user selected?
    if(nearSelected){distance.add(1);}
    if(middleSelected){distance.add(2);}
    if(farSelected){distance.add(3);}       

    //Attempt to display the number of choices picked to the user
    try {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), distance.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.i(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, attempting to get `distance.size()` causes a `NotFoundException`.  All other parts of the code run fine, just this part crashes.  Where have I screwed up?

Comment: Are you sure it is this call causing trouble? Can you post the logcat?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Distance.size()` is not what causes a `Resources.NotFoundException`, its `Toast.makeText`. When called with an *integer* as a parameter, it looks for a *string* resource with that *integer* as an id. If you want to show the number as a string, then you'll have to tell it so:

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Integer.toString(distance.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Ahhh bugger.  I should have known that.  Been coding all day and the brain just farted.  Thanks!  I'll accept as soon as the time limit is up.